# Error while opening the camera only on specific devices

Tags: java, android, android-camera, surfaceview

I am having this error on ZTE Blade A452 and thl T6C, any suggestions are highly appreciated.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1833)
at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1778)
at com.checkitmobile.tillroll2.PurchaseDetail.Receipt.OCRReceiptCaptureActivity$4.onAutoFocus(OCRReceiptCaptureActivity.java:561)
at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:1283)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Comment: post your code.

Comment: There may be many reasons for takePicture() to fail, your app should be prepared to catch this RuntimeException, and maybe try again. Having said this, have you tried to call **takePicture** on the same thread that is use for Camera callbacks?